# How to create a delayed hover action, which does not execute if user leaves before time is up? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Goals:

- Hovering over a tag for 2 secs will display a popover
- Leaving a tag will close any open popovers
- Leaving a tag before 2 secs and nothing should display

---

[image]

**Original Problem:** http://plnkr.co/edit/PDcLQNudx53Dag49FyCw?p=preview

**Failed Fix Attempt:**  http://plnkr.co/edit/39FGMocKB5GtQWnI1TFw?p=preview

I'm trying to have a delayed popover div that shows up after hovering over a `tag` div for 2 secs.

In my first plnkr above, I use `setTimeout` to add a `1.5` sec delay to the popovers.

It works fine if you hover over each item 1 by 1 slowly. However if you quickly mouse over all the tags from top to bottom or bottom to top, all at once the `setTimeout` for all items will then kick it and [popovers for multiple items get stuck in view](http://plnkr.co/edit/PDcLQNudx53Dag49FyCw?p=preview).

```
$scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {

function showDetails() {
    t.showDetails = true;
}

$timeout(showDetails, 1500);
}

$scope.leaveTag = function(t) {
    t.showDetails = false;
}
```

I'm trying to avoid this problem, if the user quickly scrolls over tags in such a manner, nothing should happen. A popover should only display if the user lingers over a tag for a couple of secs.

---

**Attempted fix:**

Somehow I need a function that is unique for each item, currently stuck below:

Markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tags">
  <div class="tag"
       ng-mouseover="showTagDetails(t)"
       ng-mouseleave="leaveTag(t)"
       ng-click="sendTag(t)">{{t.name}}</div>
  <tag-details tag="t"></tag-details>
</li>
```

Controller code:

```
var hoverTimer;

function callHoverTimer() {
  console.log('callHoverTimer');
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('true');
      return true;
  }, 2000);
}

$scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {

// function showDetails() {
//   t.showDetails = true;
// }

t.showDetails = callHoverTimer();
console.log(t.showDetails);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(t.showDetails);
}, 2000);

// $timeout(showDetails, 1500);
}

$scope.leaveTag = function(t) {
    t.showDetails = false;
}
```

---

Adding my production code which is broken as well
Below only works 1 time, if you hover and stay over a tag for 2 secs, the tagHover will display, however it will not work again once you leave:

```
var hoverTimer;

function callHoverTimer(ticker, tag) {
    hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        TagDetailsFactory.saveTagDetails(ticker, tag);
    }, 2000);
};

function hoverTag(tag) {
    var thisTicker = '';
    thisTicker = vs.ticker;

    callHoverTimer(thisTicker, tag);
};

function leaveTag(tag) {
    tagsHover = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover');
    tagsHover.leavingTag(tag);
    clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
    callHoverTimer = function(){};  // <- I can 'break' the function here, but then it's broken forever :(
};
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? `callHoverTimer = function(){};`

Comment: I definitely suggest using CSS to handle the delayed popup. The hide/show logic will be handled very smoothly and you will not need to deal with the headache of trying to set and clear timers within very short time frames, which has proven many times before to be sloppy. If you are not opposed to using CSS for this, I will be happy to post my answer, otherwise, I wish you the best of luck. Try using [`cancel[$promise]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to clear your `$timeout` instead of `clearTimeout` or `var = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to use CSS.

```
ng-class
```

and

```
.tag-details {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  transition-delay:0s;
}

.tag-details.open{
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:2s;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6SIcSzCkoPRIe34DTEbZ?p=preview

Comment: You got an upvote from me because I believe the best way to accomplish this is through the use of CSS, yet you really should provide more information with your answer.

Comment: Thanks! That is awesome, didn't even think about CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're storing and clearing the timeout at the right time.

[Here's a fixed plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWFihC87sfIEle1UZHL7?p=preview).

```
$scope.hoverTimeout = null;

$scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {
  $scope.hoverTimeout = $timeout(function() { 
    t.showDetails = true; 
  }, 1500);
}

$scope.leaveTag = function(t) {
  $timeout.cancel($scope.hoverTimeout);
  t.showDetails = false;
}
```

If you don't use `$timeout` but use `setTimeout` instead, make sure to use `$scope.$apply()` after you change anything, or Angular won't register the changes.

Comment: Thanks @AMorrise that is a clean Angular fix `+1` though I think for performance I have to go with Raul's answer.